# How to sync node_modules form inside Docker container to outside node_modules folder?

Tags: angular, docker, node-modules

is there a way to map the node modules form inside the container to the outside?

I want to install them form inside the container (so i can have consistency across platforms) but i want to copy them when they change to my node_modules folder outside the container.

Is there a simple way to do this?

I currently have docker compose version 3.
Thanks

My Dockerfile (inside frontend folder):

```
FROM 
RUN mkdir /frontend
WORKDIR /frontend

COPY . .
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli && npm install
EXPOSE 4200
CMD ['ng','serve','--host','0.0.0.0']
```

My docker-compose.yml

```
version '3'
services:
 frontend:
  build:
   context: ./frontend
   dockerfile: Dockerfile
  ports:
   - '4200:4200'
  container_name : frontend
  volumes:
   - ./frontend:/frontend
   - /frontend/node_modules
```

Comment: The `node_modules` tree itself is not necessarily consistent across host operating systems, so using a Linux-container `node_modules` on a MacOS host might not work.  On the other hand, I think just running `npm install` works consistently everywhere; I probably wouldn't bring Docker into this.

Comment: true is not consistent across os, but since you are using the container os to build them it will be... it's one of the reasons why docker is used...

Comment: Why does the `node_modules` tree need to be on the host at all, then?  You can delete the `volumes:` block to use the code built into the container.

Comment: i need it to get vs code stop highlighting every module import :/ red like it can't find them

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to have a base image and your node_modules should be there and in your main image you should use from base image.

for example you can have base image like this :

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json .
RUN npm install
```

then exec this command:

```
docker build -t base-image .
```

then use it like this:

```
FROM base-image as webapp
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
```

Comment: But then i could not install new modules while developing.

Comment: You can write a batch script that first run base image and then run main image. if your package.json file has changed base image rerun npm install